# How to get Target and url (using Api response) respose from artillery using node js

Tags: node.js

I have to get an API response simultaneously from the artillery.
This is the code getting an API response, but It's like unordered Json and return all the response at a time. However I want to single single object and a good format of Josn
Here is my code:-
This is the artillery Json:-

```
     let artilleryJson = {
        config: {
          target: target,
          phases: [
            {
              name: "Warm-up",
              duration: 20,
              rampTo: 20,
              arrivalRate: 1,
            },
          ],
        },
        scenarios: getScenarios(),
        plugins: {
          path: "./Config",
        },
      };
```

This is the function of looping the artillery

```
 function getJson(credential) {
    let json = {};
    Object.entries(credential).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      json[key] = value;
    });
    return json;
  }
  function getScenarios() {
    const scenarios = [];
    credentials.forEach((credential, index) => {
      const flow = {
        name: `Login Scenario ${index + 1}`,
        flow: [
          {
            [method]: {
              url: url,
              json: getJson(credential),
            },
          },
        ],
      };
      scenarios.push(flow);
    });
    return scenarios;
  }
```

here is my running command:-

```
 // write a file
  const convertedJson = JSON.stringify(artilleryJson, null, 2);
  fs.writeFileSync("artillery.json", convertedJson);

  // The command run the artillery and also write report in the report.json
  const artilleryExecutionCommand =
    "DEBUG=http:response artillery run --output report.json artillery.json";
  exec(artilleryExecutionCommand, async (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`Error executing command: ${error}`);
      return;
    }
    // console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);

    const apiResponse = stderr.split("http:response ")[2];
    const parsedApiResponse = JSON.parse(apiResponse);
    const artilleryOutput = require("../report.json"); });
```

Here is my output

"2023-06-24T05:58:59.439Z http:response {\n  "server": "nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)",\n  "date": "Sat, 24 Jun 2023 05:58:59 GMT",\n  "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",\n  "content-length": "27",\n  "connection": "keep-alive",\n  "x-powered-by": "Express",\n  "access-control-allow-origin": "*",\n  "etag": "W/\"1b-evcYq0xWsuHqdKUOxQRsPiOIt60\""\n}\n2023-06-24T05:58:59.439Z http:response "{\"message\":\"Invalid email\"}"\n2023-06-24T05:59:00.407Z http:response {\n  "server": "nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)",\n  "date": "Sat, 24 Jun 2023 05:59:00 GMT",\n  "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",\n  "content-length": "27",\n  "connection": "keep-alive",\n  "x-powered-by": "Express",\n  "access-control-allow-origin": "*",\n  "etag": "W/\"1b-evcYq0xWsuHqdKUOxQRsPiOIt60\""\n}\n2023-06-24T05:59:00.407Z http:response "{\"message\":\"Invalid email\"}"\n2023-06-24T05:59:00.904Z http:response {\n  "server": "nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)",\n  "date": "Sat, 24 Jun 2023 05:59:00 GMT",\n  "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",\n  "content-length": "821",\n  "connection": "keep-alive",\n  "x-powered-by": "Express",\n  "access-control-allow-origin": "*",\n  "etag": "W/\"335-iHV9LFFhta3QC0HtKcNYCcXZFG0\""\n}\n

I have to get an API response simultaneously from the artillery.
This is the code getting an API response, but It's like unordered Json and return all the response at a time. However I want to single single object and a good format of Josn
Here is my code:-
This is the artillery Json:-

```
     let artilleryJson = {
        config: {
          target: target,
          phases: [
            {
              name: "Warm-up",
              duration: 20,
              rampTo: 20,
              arrivalRate: 1,
            },
          ],
        },
        scenarios: getScenarios(),
        plugins: {
          path: "./Config",
        },
      };
```

This is the function of looping the artillery

```
 function getJson(credential) {
    let json = {};
    Object.entries(credential).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      json[key] = value;
    });
    return json;
  }
  function getScenarios() {
    const scenarios = [];
    credentials.forEach((credential, index) => {
      const flow = {
        name: `Login Scenario ${index + 1}`,
        flow: [
          {
            [method]: {
              url: url,
              json: getJson(credential),
            },
          },
        ],
      };
      scenarios.push(flow);
    });
    return scenarios;
  }
```

here is my running command:-

```
 // write a file
  const convertedJson = JSON.stringify(artilleryJson, null, 2);
  fs.writeFileSync("artillery.json", convertedJson);

  // The command run the artillery and also write report in the report.json
  const artilleryExecutionCommand =
    "DEBUG=http:response artillery run --output report.json artillery.json";
  exec(artilleryExecutionCommand, async (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`Error executing command: ${error}`);
      return;
    }
    // console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);

    const apiResponse = stderr.split("http:response ")[2];
    const parsedApiResponse = JSON.parse(apiResponse);
    const artilleryOutput = require("../report.json"); });
```

Here is my output

"2023-06-24T05:58:59.439Z http:response {\n  "server": "nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)",\n  "date": "Sat, 24 Jun 2023 05:58:59 GMT",\n  "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",\n  "content-length": "27",\n  "connection": "keep-alive",\n  "x-powered-by": "Express",\n  "access-control-allow-origin": "*",\n  "etag": "W/\"1b-evcYq0xWsuHqdKUOxQRsPiOIt60\""\n}\n2023-06-24T05:58:59.439Z http:response "{\"message\":\"Invalid email\"}"\n2023-06-24T05:59:00.407Z http:response {\n  "server": "nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)",\n  "date": "Sat, 24 Jun 2023 05:59:00 GMT",\n  "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",\n  "content-length": "27",\n  "connection": "keep-alive",\n  "x-powered-by": "Express",\n  "access-control-allow-origin": "*",\n  "etag": "W/\"1b-evcYq0xWsuHqdKUOxQRsPiOIt60\""\n}\n2023-06-24T05:59:00.407Z http:response "{\"message\":\"Invalid email\"}"\n2023-06-24T05:59:00.904Z http:response {\n  "server": "nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)",\n  "date": "Sat, 24 Jun 2023 05:59:00 GMT",\n  "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",\n  "content-length": "821",\n  "connection": "keep-alive",\n  "x-powered-by": "Express",\n  "access-control-allow-origin": "*",\n  "etag": "W/\"335-iHV9LFFhta3QC0HtKcNYCcXZFG0\""\n}\n